# React component loses focus on each keystroke

Tags: reactjs, typescript, codemirror

so I have a code editor component that is losing focus on each keystroke [like in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pB5OUa0JliY&t=7s).

Below is my react component. I have an event listener, in it `updateRuleBody` is being fired off, each time there is a change. updateRuleBody is updating the rule, according to the changes made in the editor.

```
const Codemirror: React.FC<{

  editorInitialValue: string | undefined;
  editorRule: Query | Suppression | undefined;
  updateRuleBody: typeof updateRuleBody;

}> = ({editorInitialValue, editorRule, updateRuleBody, }) => {


  const [editorValue, setEditorValue] = useState<string>('');
  const [editorTreeValue, setEditorTreeValue] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const editor = useRef<EditorView>();

  const onUpdate = (editorRule: any) =>
    EditorView.updateListener.of((view: ViewUpdate) => {
      const editorDocument = view.state.doc;

      const docString = editorDocument.toString();

      cmstore.dispatch(updateEditorValue(docString));
      updateRuleBody(editorRule?.viewName.toString(), docString);
    });

  // Initailize view
  useEffect(
    function initEditorView() {
      const elem = document.getElementById('codemirror-editor')!;
      if (editor.current) {
        elem.children[0].remove();
      }

      editor.current = new EditorView({
        state: EditorState.create({
          doc: editorInitialValue,
          extensions: [
            lineNumbers(),
            highlightSpecialChars(),
            history(),
            foldGutter(),
            drawSelection(),
            EditorState.allowMultipleSelections.of(true),
            indentOnInput(),
            Prec.fallback(defaultHighlightStyle),
            bracketMatching(),
            closeBrackets(),
            autocompletion(),
            rectangularSelection(),
            highlightActiveLine(),
            highlightSelectionMatches(),
            keymap.of([
              ...closeBracketsKeymap,
              ...defaultKeymap,
              ...searchKeymap,
              ...historyKeymap,
              ...foldKeymap,
              ...commentKeymap,
              ...completionKeymap,
            ]),
            sql(),
            oneDark,
            onUpdate(editorRule),
          ],
        }),
        parent: elem as Element,
      });
    },
    [editorInitialValue],
  );
```

The intention of using `editorInitialValue` is for the editor to have a selected query loaded with it.

```
 Class RawEditor extends React.Component<RawEditorProps> {
  render(): JSX.Element {
    const {currentRuleView, deleteRule, saveRule, updateRuleBody} = this.props;
    const {queries, suppressions} = this.props.rules;
    const rules = [...queries, ...suppressions];
    const rule = rules.find((r) => r.viewName === currentRuleView);
    return (
      <div>
          <Codemirror  
             editorInitialValue={ rule ? rule?.raw.body.toString():''}
            editorRule={rule}
            updateRuleBody={updateRuleBody}
          />
```

Above is a part of the parent component, where Codemirror is getting its props from.

The re-renders happen because of the changes that are being made and thus the editor is losing its focus, I have tried using key and react.memo but it's not helping.

Would really appreciate any suggestions!

Update: Fixed the issue by not using useEffect to change rules (think contents of the editor)

Comment: This happens when you create the input component as a variable inside another component.  It gets recreated on each render instead of just being updated with new props.  But there's a lot going on in this code with external libraries that I don't understand.

Comment: Thank you :) Managed to solve it

Comment: You should post an answer with your solution.  It’s okay to answer your own question and it can help anyone else who has a similar problem.